# Why cannot use python3 to import the class "PollIOLoop" from tornado.ioloop?

Tags: import, tornado

I encountered a problem when importing the class "PollIOLoop" from tornado.ioloop, I don't know how to use, just need it in one file. The original code is "from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PollIOLoop", but I would get the error——ImportError: cannot import name 'PollIOLoop'. I've tried to reinstall tornado but didn't solve. Then I found that I can import both IOLoop and PollIOLoop when using python2 explicitly in the terminal:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Mar  8 2023, 18:40:28) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tornado
>>> from tornado.ioloop import PollIOLoop
>>> from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
>>> exit()
```

When switching to python3, it would output  error:

```
Python 3.6.13 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun  4 2021, 14:25:59) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tornado
>>> from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
>>> from tornado.ioloop import PollIOLoop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'PollIOLoop'
```

Do anybody know what's the problem with this? And if I want to use the"from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PollIOLoop" in python3, what should I do? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `PollIOLoop` class was removed from Tornado years ago. It was in old version (maybe 4.5).